# How to set bash profile remotely using perl and run a script

Tags: ssh

i have a perl script which connects to remote server , edits a file ,runs some scripts in the remote server.

Here is the code

```
   my $host= mx4d4;
   my $FILE1 = 'Abc.conf' ;#this is a ; separted file
   my $FILE2 = 'MyCode.py'; #python script 
    sub do_operation()
    {
    my $server="197.0.0.1"; #Just for the sake of example , this gets populated at my end
    #Run the commands remotely
    #change 3rd and 4th column to NEWSTR
    system(
       'ssh' => ('-q', $server),
       'sed' => ('-i -E', qq('/$host/s#([^;]+;[^;]+;)[^;]+;[^;]+#\\1NEWSTR,NEWSTR #)'),$FILE1),
    #change 4th and 5th column to STR
    system(
       'ssh' => ('-q', $server),
       'sed' => ('-i -E', qq('/$host/s#([^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;)[^;]+;[^;]+#\\1NEWSTR,NEWSTR #'),$FILE1),
    #Run python script
    system(
       'ssh' => ('-q', $server),
       '$FILE2' => ('--run'),
    ) 
    }
```

Issues :

1. In the 3rd System command above , i am not able to run the PYTHON SCRPT successfully as i need to set the remote environment profile (using set_profile.sh )before running the python script , how to set the profile and run the python script at the same time in same system call.
2. Is it possible to have all 3 operations under only one system call

Comment: I think you can set the environment in the same ssh command like this: `ssh $server "source set_profile.sh;  MyCode.py"`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: i tried but its failing , also there needs to be a way to run multiple commands as we are running it using system and it has hash too.        'ssh' => ('-q', $server; MyCode.py ) throws a syntax error

Comment: You seem to have missed the double quotes in your last comment. It should be like this: `'ssh' => ('-q', "$server; MyCode.py" )`

Comment: @HåkonHægland : Yeah sorry, i missed in code too, with ssh' => ('-q', $server; MyCode.py )   , there is no syntax error but it doesnt run the python script too

Comment: Note that your last comment also lacks double quotes around the command

Answer (score 1):

The command you execute with ssh is run using the default shell on the remote machine. According to the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html):

> If a command is specified, it will be executed on the remote host
> instead of a login shell.  A complete command line may be specified
> as command, or it may have additional arguments.  If supplied, the
> arguments will be appended to the command, separated by spaces,
> before it is sent to the server to be executed.

So you can do for example the following to run multiple commands in a single session:

```
system "ssh", $server, "echo \$SHELL; echo \$HOSTNAME; export FOO=bar; echo \$FOO";
```

### Example output

```
/bin/bash
openssh-server
bar
```

Comment: Thank you for this , i did try this solution just now but without system,
ex : `  ssh ,  $server, " cd $app_folder ; source .profile; cd $py_folder; ./Mycode.py";
and this runs the code ,but i am not able to see the output log,

Comment: If you are using backticks inside a Perl script to run `ssh`, you should not use comma to separate arguments. The comma is only needed when giving argument list to `system`

Comment: And the only positive in the below way 
 system(
       'ssh' => ('-q', $server),
       '$FILE2' => ('--run'),
    )  is i can see the output  on screen

Comment: oh sorry , indeed i did not use the commas , thats why it works but no output, ni am typing the whole thing here and this is not my official laptop , its a typo

Comment: Ok, to print the output use can use the `print` command. E.g. `print \`echo Hello\``

Comment: To be clear all my commands are part of a hash and i call it to t=run the code and the print is just not working here` ssh $server " cd $app_folder ; source .profile; cd $py_folder; print $commands-> {"file2.py"}  " ` ;

Comment: To debug this, could you try to run e.g. `ssh $server "cd $app_folder; echo \$PWD"` from the shell (not from the perl script)? Note: replace `$server` and `$app_folder` with their actual values in the previous command. Do you get the expected output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251861/discussion-between-learningcpp-and-hakon-haegland).